# I need a mouse for my mom

Tags: mice

The mouse will have to have thumb button.

It must have a button like logitech mouse that can switch between computers

It's scrolling button must be clickable as middle button.

I prefer a touch screen like mac mouse actually.

Price up to $200

Basically I want something like

https://www.tokopedia.com/catalog/50361/logitech-mx-anywhere-2

I have big problem with it's middle button. I can't have middle button. The scrolling wheel doesn't work as middle button. The scrolling wheel act as a switch between smooth scrolling and something, which I totally do not need.

Also it's too expensive.

I want simpler mouse for mom.
I sort of like

It seems that many high end logitech mouse has a stupid feature (I don't know what's the name). Basically the wheel has 2 mode. Free scroll and fine scrolling. So the wheel button doesn't work. The button behind the wheel works as a way to switch between fine scrolling and free scrolling. I hate that feature. I am happy with normal free scrolling and prefer middle button instead.

Comment: The product you linked is sold for less than $100 bucks, yet you say it's too expensive. Is your budget 200 or 100 bucks?

Comment: Logitech Mx Anywhere has this stupid feature where clicking the scroll button will change between 2 mode. I don't want that feature. Price is actually fine. Because it's not gaming mouse I think cheaper is better. Also I prefer touch screen scroll wheel.

Comment: http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/m720-triathlon?crid=7 is good but same problem. Also I think the switch computer should be on the bottom of the mouse so not accidentally clicked

Comment: I'm almost certain the logitech software will let you disable or customize any button on the mouse... My cheapo logitech mouse at home does this...

Comment: no. I've checked. I've asked. I've looked on the web.